# a problem in class in class-wp-hook.php

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, themes, function-exists

I get the problem this morning

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
> callback, function 'wp_ob_end_flush_all' not found or invalid function
> name in /home/legotechnic/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
> line 308

any one one has any idea to how to fix it please ?

Comment: Did you just start seeing this warning? What has changed - core/theme/plugin updates, PHP version change? It looks like something—a plugin or a theme, most likely—is trying to use [`wp_ob_end_flush_all()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ob_end_flush_all/) before it's available, ie, too early in the WordPress loading sequence.